# speed calculation linear algebra

Tags: vector, wolfram-mathematica, physics, game-physics

I have some case on linear algebra and I have not found solutions for this case. Additional i have not methematica background. I have three players. I know velocity and position each od them. Also I have some point (another Vector). I want to calculate how many time take to reach this point by each od these players. Could somebody help me ? I have read: http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/

But it is not my case :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this in 3 dimensions, or shorten the vectors for 2 dimensions

```
player1position={1,2,7};
player1velocity=5;
pointposition={2,4,5};
time=Norm[player1position-pointposition]/player1velocity
```

Comment: Norm is function from which programming language ? I use a Java but there shuld be analogical method.

Comment: Norm is a function in the Wolfram Mathematica programming language and documented here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html  You included the Wolfram-Mathematica tag in your posting and used the word mathematica in your posting so I assumed you were trying to understand how to use Mathematica http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/?source=nav

Comment: I understand, I did it being not aware :(

Comment: But one more thing. I have velocity in 2 dimensions. What IT change in this algorithm ?

Comment: Assuming your player is traveling on a line between the original position and the point destination then only `player1position={1,2}; pointposition={2,4};` change. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: This I know, but I ask about velocity. On your example is scalar value player1velocity = 5. On my case player1velocity = {2,5} - the number is example. Stil I can use yours algorithm ? But how ? I shuld calculate lenght from my player1velocity Vector ?

Comment: Maybe also you know some good tutorial for linear algebra for beginers games dev where are similar case as my ? The beat what I have found is http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/, but there are no my cases.

Comment: Perhaps something like `player1position={1,2};
player1velocity={1,1};
pointposition={3,4};
Solve[player1position+t*player1velocity==pointposition,t]` but since you are not using Mathematica this may have little use for you. That will also only have a solution if that velocity vector defines a line from player1position to point. I don't know how much background you have. I assume you know little about linear algebra. "Coding the Matrix" uses Python, but it tries to teach linear algebra by writing software. Perhaps you could see a copy of that and see if it would be the kind of book you want.

Comment: So, Thank you very much for help @Bill :)